# Extract multiples strings from one variable by using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having troubles extracting several strings between tags from a variable, in order to echo them inside a span individually.
Thing is, the tags in question are determined by a variable, here is what it looks like :

```
<?php
    $string = "[en_UK]english1[/en_UK][en_UK]english2[/en_UK][fr_FR]francais1[/fr_FR][fr_FR]francais2[/fr_FR][fr_FR]francais3[/fr_FR]";
    $lang = "en_UK";

    preg_match("/(.[$lang]), (.[\/$lang])/", $string, $outputs_list);

    foreach ($outputs_list as $output) {
        echo "<span>".$output."/span>";
    }

    // in this exemple I want to output :
    // <span>english1</span>
    // <span>english2</span>
?>
```

It's my first time using preg_match and after trying so many differents things I'm kinda lost right now.
Basically I want to extract every strings contained between the tags [`$lang`] and [/`$lang`] (in my exemple `$lang = "en_UK"` but it will be determined by the user's cookies.

I'd like some help figuring this out if possible,

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I kinda got lost in my attempts. How ever do you think the $lang will output "en_UK" in your code ? Or do I need to escape it like `preg_match_all("/\[".$lang."\](.+?)\[\/".$lang."\]/", $string, $outputs_list);`? Thanks !

Comment: Either or will work since you are in double quotes. I've moved that down as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` in a regular expression makes a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `.`s and `,` either. Your regex currently says:

Any single character, an `e`, `n`, `_`, `U`, or `K`, a `,` and space, and again any single character, an `e`, `n`, `_`, `U`, `K`, but this time also allowing `/`.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/8pmy89/2

I also believe you were grouping the wrong value. The `()` go around what you want to capture, know as a `capture group`.

I think the regex you want is:

```
\[$lang\](.+?)\[\/$lang\]
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/8pmy89/3

PHP Usage:

```
$string = "[en_UK]english1[/en_UK][en_UK]english2[/en_UK][fr_FR]francais1[/fr_FR][fr_FR]francais2[/fr_FR][fr_FR]francais3[/fr_FR]";
$lang = "en_UK";
preg_match_all("/\[$lang\](.+?)\[\/$lang\]/", $string, $outputs_list);
foreach ($outputs_list[1] as $output) {
    echo "<span>".$output."/span>";
}
```

PHP demo: https://eval.in/686086

**Preg_match vs. preg_match_all**

`Preg_match` only returns the first match(es) of a regex. `Preg_match_all` returns all matches of the regex. The `0` index has what the full regex matched. All subsequent indexes are each capture groups, e.g. `1` is the first capture group.

Simple Demo: https://eval.in/686116

```
$string = '12345';
preg_match('/(\d)/', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
preg_match_all('/(\d)/', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
```

^ is `preg_match`, below is the `preg_match_all`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is now working. However I don't understand what the [1] after $outputs_list stand for ? And one final question that I didn't add to my original question to simplify things : if instead of $lang I have `$user['lang']` Do I need to escape it in a particular way or is it gonna work if I leave it like this ?

Comment: And thanks for detailling your answer as much, indeed my capture group was basically null in my attempt.

Comment: Preg_match_all makes multiple matches, the 1 index is the first capture group

Answer (score 1):

I made little late to post this answer. @chris already answered your question, so i made the solution broad which might help other users who may have different requirements.

```
<?php
$string = "[en_UK]english1[/en_UK][en_UK]english2[/en_UK][fr_FR]francais1[/fr_FR][fr_FR]francais2[/fr_FR][fr_FR]francais3[/fr_FR]";
$lang = "en_UK";
echo "User Language -";
preg_match_all("/\[$lang\](.+?)\[\/$lang\]/", $string, $outputs_list);
foreach ($outputs_list[1] as $output) {
    echo "<span>".$output.",</span>";
}
echo "<br/>All languages - ";
//if all lang
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}/", $string, $outputs_list);
foreach ($outputs_list[0] as $output) {
    echo "<span>".$output.",</span>";
}
echo "<br/>Type of lang - ";
//for showing all type of lang
preg_match_all("/(\[[a-zA-Z_]+\])*/", $string, $outputs_list);
foreach ($outputs_list[1] as $output) {
    echo "<span>".$output."</span>";
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

> User Language -english1,english2,
>
> All languages - english1,english2,francais1,francais2,francais3,
>
> Type of lang - [en_UK][en_UK][fr_FR][fr_FR][fr_FR]

Comment: @chris85, Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. It will be helpful to other users